# Getting multiple local notifications when I should only get one

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have an application that suppose to send me a local notification when detects my beacons which can be configured in my app.
So initially If I have one beacon in range, I’ll get a local notification alert that says 
“Beacon is in range”
So when beacon is out of range and in range again, I get another notification.
Now if I add one more beacon, when both are in range at the same time I get 2 notifications which is fine and that is what I want.
However now if I turn off one of the beacon, when the other one is in range, I suppose to get 1 notification but for some reason I still get 2 notifications?

Is there something I need to clear after I get notifications that prevent this from happening?

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    myTitle = "Entering the range"
    var alertView = UIAlertController(title: myTitle, message: "Press OK to continue", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: yesHandler))
    presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    alertBody1 = "Beacon is in range"
    LocalNotification() 
}    
func yesHandler(actionTarget: UIAlertAction!){
    print("YES -> !!");
}

func LocalNotification() {
    var notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    let dateTime = NSDate()
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
    notification.alertAction = "Beacon Range detection"
    notification.alertBody = alertBody1
    notification.soundName = "chime.wav"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Comment: How are your CLBeaconRegions set up for monitoring?  What beacon identifiers are you using to test?

Comment: For simplicity, let say I have these 2 lines //
let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: 10004, minor: 5178, identifier: "MyBeacon") let beaconRegion2 = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: 10004, minor: 5178, identifier: "MyBeacon2") locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion) //
locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion2)

Comment: Do you really intend for both regions to have the same UUID/major/minor or is this a typo?

Comment: No that is typo. Each have a different UUID/Major/Minor

Comment: It is unclear what is causing the problem, but it is probably in the region configuration.  If you cannot show this code, it will be difficult to find a solution in this forum.  If the code is too complex to show, I suggest you simplify, and try to reproduce the problem with a simpler set of region definitions for the sake of getting help in this forum.

Comment: ok, I'll make a simple version and will share it. thanks for your help